# Checking for Dict Elements within a List (from json response)

Tags: json, list, dictionary, key

I currently query this API recursively, and for each instance which I send in a request, I want to check inside the returned json for whether there are any objects within the parameter "causes_virtual". If there is an existing entry inside there, such as in this case: `"id": 5408600`, I want to `print('Contains Entry')` but if there is nothing within, I want to `print('No Entry')`. How can I check `causes_virtual` for whether or not it contains any additional elements within the curly braces? Currently I am using the method of checking for an empty list:

Either:  `if len(api_response_article[0]['causes_virtual']) == 0:` or  `if not api_response_article[0]['causes_virtual']:`

However, neither of these methods seem to do me any good because it seems to only check for items as if it was a traditional list, but from my understanding, it is a dictionary within a list.

```
{
    "additional_info": "",
    "approved_at": null,
    "approved_by_id": null,
    "causes_virtual": [           # THIS SECTION
        {
            "id": 5408600,
            "models": [
                "Potatoes"
            ],
            "principals": "Some irrelevant text",
            "title": "We farm potatoes or something"
        }
    ],
    "created_at": "2021-03-03T01:13:04.477348+00:00",
    "created_by_id": 1019500
}
```

I suppose what I am looking for is the right `if` statement for seeing if there is anything inside `causes_virtual`.
Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So, do you want to check if there's a dictionary that contains key `id` inside the list `causes_virtual`?

Comment: I just want to check and see whether or not there is anything that is inside of causes_virtual. It would be a bonus if I could find out exactly what is inside, but for the time being, just knowing if another dict element exists inside of causes_virtual would be useful. A `causes_virtual` without anything inside of it would look like `"causes_virtual" : []`

Comment: It might also be worth noting that when I do: 
`print(api_response_article[0]['causes_virtual'])`, I get returned [] , regardless of whether or not there is anything inside of  causes_virtual